# Temporarily disable laptop built-in keyboard on Windows 10, is it possible?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

This has been asked here many times, but no answer still applies.

Is it possible to **temporarily** disable my laptop's built-in keyboard, on up-to-date **Windows 10** Pro?

Given that:

- On **Device Manager**, the "disable" button for the Keyboard device is greyed out.
- Uninstalling or replacing the driver with a dummy one is not an option because this requires restarting the PC in order to enable it again.
- On NirSoft **DevManView** the "Disable" action returns `Error -536870351: Unknown Error` and makes it appear as disabled, but the keyboard is still 100% functional.

I need to easily turn the built-in keyboard off, so I can use a external (USB or Bluetooth) keyboard on top of it sometimes. Is there any way of doing this without having to reboot Windows both when I want to disable it, and when I need to re-enable it back?

Maybe some tweak, flag or something on the Registry, to allow the "Disable" action on Device Manager, or some utility that can selectively disable only the built-in one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just use the external keyboard without disabling the built-in one?

Comment: I use it on top of the built-in one. Every now and then some accidental key pressing occurs. If what I'm asking is indeed not possible, I'll end up buying a larger 2nd keyboard and/or placing something between it and the built-in one to avoid the accidental strokes...