# How to disable built-in keyboard of laptop programmatically?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, drivers, keyboard

I'm trying to disable my built-in keyboard as the `Windows` and `P` keys keep sticking and "project screen" always pops up. My solution was to remove the driver for the keyboard.

I've tried looking on the internet for how to remove the driver for the built-in keyboard. However, it's not permanent. After a few restarts, the driver comes back and the built-in keyboard is no longer disabled. [Sample link that I tried.](https://www.lifewire.com/disable-laptop-keyboard-windows-10-4582462)

Since it keeps on coming back, I'm thinking of using a script to automatically follow the steps to remove the driver. How can I disable the built-in keyboard of my laptop using a script? Or how can I permanently remove the driver?

I checked the questions below, but they are not answered and are not asking for a script.

[Temporarily disable laptop built-in keyboard on Windows 10, is it possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/1536548/temporarily-disable-laptop-built-in-keyboard-on-windows-10-is-it-possible)

[Disabling the built in keyboard and using an external USB keyboard](https://superuser.com/questions/1640395/disabling-the-built-in-keyboard-and-using-an-external-usb-keyboard)

Comment: A bit too heavy as a solution. What do you mean by "Windows + P sticks" and by "always popup"?

Comment: It's like you clicked on Windows + P on your keyboard then the Project screen shows on your right panel. But in this case, you are not pressing anything. It's just itself clicking Windows + P continuously. Turns out you can do nothing.

Comment: What is the model of the keyboard? What driver version is currently installed? I suppose you're using an external keyboard? Have you tried the two methods given in your sample link?

Comment: Model: ACPI\HPQ8001. Version: 10.0.19041.1. Yes, I got external keyboard. Also yes, I did those. I checked the Event logs. I got this repeatedly. Device deleted, after less than a minute, Device configured (keyboard.inf) and 8 seconds after, its now Device started (i8042prt)

Comment: The second method breaks the device by installing a wrong driver.

Comment: Yes, it must. However, its not working on my end.

Comment: You could perhaps use [this method](https://superuser.com/a/968749/8672) to stop Windows updating the driver.

Comment: I tried to but it's no good.

Comment: Then replacing the bad keyboard, or repeating the disabling of the keyboard, is the solution. If required, a logon script can do it as well.

Comment: Tagged as "windows-terminal", but doesn't seem to have anything to do with that program.  There actually *is* a way to disable keyboard in Windows Terminal, but that doesn't appear to be what you want.  Could you update the question to clarify, or remove the "windows-terminal" tag?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Long time since I've used Windows, but I guess you could just *disable* it in the Device Manager:

1. Press `Win+X`.
2. Navigate to `Device Manager`.
3. Right click on the device you want to disable.
4. Click **Disable**.
5. Reboot to see if it worked.

Another solution might be to not allow the reinstallation of drivers. Please keep in mind that this means you might have to manually install drivers for any new peripheral you connect:

1. Press `Win+R` and type `gpedit.msc` in the box.
2. On the left side pane in the window that pops up, navigate to `Computer Configuration` > `Administrative Templates` > `System` > `Device Installation` > `Device Installation Restrictions`.
3. Right click on `Prevent Installation of Devices not described by other policy settings`.
4. Change the option from `Not configured` to `Disabled`.
5. Exit.
6. Press `Win+X`.
7. Click `Device Manager`.
8. Right click on the device you want to remove and choose **Uninstall**.
9. Reboot your PC to see if the changes stuck.

Please let me know if that worked. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar needs: cleaning lady always touch the keyboard wanna disable it and enable it with scheduled task. Disable at 5pm enable at 8am

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).